# Change the navigation bar to an image

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

I have an image in my Xcode project, and it is currently set to the same dimensions as the tab bar. I have the navigation bar set up through a storyboard, not programatically. I want the appearance of the navigation bar to come from my image. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];
[navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Two errors No known class method for selector 'setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:' and second one is " Unknown receiver 'NavigationBar'; did you mean 'UINavigationBar'? "

Comment: @JonathanClendenon Try self.navigationBar

Comment: @JonathanClendenon Try self.navigationcontroller.navigationbar

Comment: new error Property 'navigationcontroller' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'

Comment: @JonathanClendenon Are you using a navigation controller?

Comment: oh no, its a tabbar application

Comment: @JonathanClendenon Select your view controller with the navigation bar. On top select editor->embed in->navigation controller.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34105/discussion-between-jonathan-and-abdullah-shafique)

Comment: @jonathan Connect an outlet from your navigation bar

Comment: @jonathan Then use the code I told you in my answer but switch navigationBar with your outlet name.

Comment: @jonathan Remember the check and plus 1.